# When I'm trying to update a record I get error #1062 - Duplicate entry for key 'ID_UNIQUE'

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I'm using the following stored-procedure to update a table:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`developer`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `update_patient`(IN `patient_id` INT(11), IN `name` VARCHAR(45), IN `surname` VARCHAR(45), IN `middle_name` VARCHAR(45), IN `email` VARCHAR(45), IN `phone` VARCHAR(45), IN `mobile` VARCHAR(45), IN `address_id` INT(11), IN `address_no` VARCHAR(8), IN `ID` VARCHAR(45), IN `DOB` DATE)
    NO SQL
UPDATE
  patient
SET name  = name,
  surname = surname,
  middle_name = middle_name,
  email = email,
  phone = phone,
  mobile = mobile,
  address_id = address_id,
  address_no = address_no,
  ID = ID,
  DOB = DOB      
WHERE
  patient_id = patient_id
LIMIT 1;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

When I'm trying to call it through `phpmyadmin` I get the error: `#1062 - Duplicate entry '844844' for key 'ID_UNIQUE'`

`844844` refers to `ID` field. I have this field in `patient` table and I want to update the patient's data. However, the primary key of patient table is `patiend_id` and not `ID`.

Do you know how to fix the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your input params for the Stored procedure are same as your column names in the table. This is leading to ambiguous behaviour.

Eg: In `SET name  = name` ; how does MySQL resolve which one of this is the param value and which one is the column name ?

I generally prefix `IN` params with `in_` and `OUT` with `out_` for code readability and avoiding ambiguous behaviour.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE definer=`developer`@`localhost`
PROCEDURE `update_patient`(IN `in_patient_id`  INT(11),
                           IN `in_name`        VARCHAR(45),
                           IN `in_surname`     VARCHAR(45),
                           IN `in_middle_name` VARCHAR(45),
                           IN `in_email`       VARCHAR(45),
                           IN `in_phone`       VARCHAR(45),
                           IN `in_mobile`      VARCHAR(45),
                           IN `in_address_id`  INT(11),
                           IN `in_address_no`  VARCHAR(8),
                           IN `in_id`          VARCHAR(45),
                           IN `in_dob`         date)
  NO SQL

  UPDATE patient
  SET    name = in_name,
         surname = in_surname,
         middle_name = in_middle_name,
         email = in_email,
         phone = in_phone,
         mobile = in_mobile,
         address_id = in_address_id,
         address_no = in_address_no,
         id = in_id,
         dob = in_dob
  WHERE  patient_id = in_patient_id
  LIMIT  1;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```